# ViewResolver is not working when I add the mvc:resources

Tags: java, xml, spring, jsp

Am new to spring, my testproject having with 4 jsp pages. these are working fine
When I integrated with a third party tool which is having one more JSP page
(in view there is only one jsp page and multiple JS, css and images). It is also working fine, but js and images are not loading.

So I added below statement to `spring-serlvet` xml file

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
```

But after adding this statement not working ( unable to navigate to other pages, only getting first getting firstpage)

Below are my configurations :-

**spring-serlvet.xml**

```
<bean  class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView"/>
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>

<context:annotation-config/> 

<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
```

**web.xml**

```
<listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.util.WebAppRootListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<servlet>
      <servlet-name>firstSpring</servlet-name>
      <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>firstSpring</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

**Console log**

```
 org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping - Mapped URL path [/resources/**] onto handler 'org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler#0'
 org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - FrameworkServlet 'firstSpring': initialization completed in 1890 ms
 org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound - No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/firstSpring/indextonext] in DispatcherServlet with name 'firstSpring'
```

`Using spring 4.2.5`

Comment: Do you have <mvc:annotation-driven /> in your spring-serlvet.xml

Comment: @Yogi No, I don't have... I am trying now by adding this.. will share the output

Comment: @Yogi I added `<mvc:annotation-driven />` and removed `<context:annotation-config/>` tag. Now it's working... Thank you :)